# Is it good to use migrations for old database in Codeigniter or Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, codeigniter, migration

I have a started project in Codeigniter. I thought I will use some part of already created sections of similar site. So I have copied the old database and started work.
On that time it has around 40+ tables and has thousands of rows of data.

Then after I setup my environment for this new project, several tables created and all of those used migrations. It's then setup in development environment, so other team members can also work on.

Now I found old users and lots of data that I copied from old project not required
I decided to remove all tables that is not required for current project.
And need to remove all users and related data that was actually came from old project. Now database has 49 tables and I need only around 10 tables for my current project.

Question is Should I use migration to clear an old database?
Should I use migration to remove thousands of old data that are mixed with development data.
Should I use migration to alter several tables where lots of column not required for my current project?

Please provide suggestions
.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, migrations are there to keep a track of the structure of the database.

If your old database is not defined in migrations, there is no point to create migrations to remove unused tables. You can clean them manually.
But if you have made migrations for that old DB, then you can create new ones to clean it up.

Anything related to the actual data in the database should be placed within seeders nor custom command *(e.g. `php artisan make:command CleanData`)*

The reason is that if you ever need to [squash your migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#squashing-migrations), you will lose any instructions related to data.